# how to export adobe xd for flutter which display the same at all android and ios phone?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, adobe-xd

I use adobe xd for Designing UI for flutter and I use xd to flutter plugin
Is there a way for these designs to be displayed the same in all versions of Android and ios?
With different screen sizes?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Make the app responsive

> To enable Responsive Resize:
>
> 1. Select the artboard in Design mode.
> 2. In the Property inspector, click the power button to toggle Responsive Resize on.

More infos [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/user-guide.html/de/xd/help/using-responsive-resize.ug.html)

With this Adobe will scale your App responsive.

Flutter also automatically scales its apps in a responsive manner

### Adobe XD to Flutter

To port your App from Adobe XD to Flutter you can use [this](https://adobe.com/go/xd_plugins_discover_plugin?pluginId=6eaf77ea) Adobe XD plugin.

[Here a full totorial about this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSCJDrUPvuI)

But it can always be that some things are not transmitted correctly, so I would recommend that you know a little about Flutter.